# Initializing an object with a property that is dependent on another property

Tags: c#

Consider this class

```
class SomeObject
{
        private int x;
        public int X
        {
            get { return x; }
            set { x = value+z; }
        }

        private int y;
        public int Y
        {
            get { return y; }
            set { y = value+z ; }
        }

        private int z;
        public int Z
        {
            get {return z;}
            set { z = value+y ; }
        }
    }
```

When I do something like

```
var r = new SomeObject() {X = 1, Y = 1, Z = 1 };
Console.WriteLine(r.X + " " + r.Y + " " + r.Z);

var r1 = new SomeObject() { Y = 1, X = 1, Z = 1 };
Console.WriteLine(r1.X + " " + r1.Y + " " + r1.Z);

var r2 = new SomeObject() { Z = 1, X = 1, Y = 1 };
Console.WriteLine(r2.X + " " + r2.Y + " " + r2.Z);
```

The console outputs

```
1 1 2
1 1 2
2 2 1
```

Is there a way to fix this behaviour other than using the constructor?

The right output shall be `2 2 2`

**every answer was helpful but i can't marke them all as best answer**

Comment: Well it works good, as when you are initalizing particular variables the others are **0**, and I'm not really sure it's possible, but you could try to bind them using `INotifyPropertyChanged`, so they could **adapt** to most actual value of each variable, after every change. For more information about this interface check: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of storing the value with the dependent variable, you could always compute it only in the getter. This way the order they get set wouldn't matter. For example

```
    private int y;
    public int Y
    {
        get { return y +z; }
        set { y = value ; }
    }
```

and similar for the other properties.

However I must add that what you're trying to achieve through properties is counter-intuitive and can be problem for any other programmer coming across this.

Comment: does this also mean less memory usage?

Comment: @user1492051 No this wouldn't have any implication on the memory usage. You're still storing values in separate variables. Do you have any reason to worry about the memory usage? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: could you please explain why its counter-intuitive?

Comment: Normally setter and getter go together as pairs. Setter is supposed to be a place to do validation (and raise exceptions) or do necessary computation. However as another commenter has pointed out getter should normally return the value that was set. In some rare cases you might in your class decide to ignore the value that was set - for example Height = 300 when MaxHeight = 200. You may ignore the setter. But to always return a different value for a getter from the set value is quite unusual.

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem. Perfectly correct behavior. When you're setting `Z` first it will work as you expect. Otherwise `Z` is 0 while you're setting other properties and `value + Z == value`.

Just use constructor:

```
public SomeObject(int x, int y, int z)
{
   this.x = x + z;
   this.y = y + z;
   this.z = z + y;
}
```

You can always use named parameters:

```
var r = new SomeObject(x: 1, z: 1, y: 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is terrible, don't modify value in `set` accessor.

If I set value `Y = 10` I'd like to see that `10` back.

I would do something like this with readonly properties

```
public int XModified
{
    get { return x + z; }
}
```

and so on.